# clearInterval doesnt stop loop

Tags: javascript, svg, setinterval, clearinterval

I have the following code

```
startProgressTimer: function () {
    var me = this,
        updateProgressBars = function (eventItems) {
            alert("updateProgressBars: looping");
            alert("me.eventProgressTimerId:" + me.eventProgressTimerId);
            var i = 0;
            if (eventItems.length === 0) {
                alert("internal Stop Begin")
                clearInterval(me.eventProgressTimerId);
                alert("internal Stop End")
                eventItems = [];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < eventItems.length; i++) {
                if (eventItems[i]._eventId) {
                    eventItems[i].updateProgressBar();
                }
            }
        };
    alert("Start Progress Timer");
    this.eventProgressTimerId = setInterval(function () {
        updateProgressBars([]);
    }, 10000);
}
```

When the function is called I would expect it to run and bottom out only it keeps on looping.

screen output

```
ALERT:updateProgressBars: looping
ALERT:me.eventProgressTimerId:10
ALERT:internal Stop Begin
ALERT:internal Stop End
ALERT:updateProgressBars: looping
ALERT:me.eventProgressTimerId:10
ALERT:internal Stop Begin
ALERT:internal Stop End
```

Any ideas

Comment: How many times is `startProgressTimer()` called? If it's called more than once on the same instance and you store the interval id as an instance variable you'd only be able to cancel the last one. Why not declare your `eventProgressTimerId` variable as a local variable within `startProgressTimer()`?

Comment: Hey excellent, a bit of tweaking and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: In that case perhaps I'll rephrase my comment as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem might be that the code you don't show calls the `startProgressTimer()` method more than once for the same instance of whatever object it belongs to, and then within the method you store the interval id in an instance property `this.eventProgressTimerId` - so multiple calls overwrite the property and you'd only be able to cancel the last one.

If that's the case, a simple fix is to declare your `eventProgressTimerId` as a local variable within startProgressTimer().